# Transform values of a dictionary to new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{
    'doc0': {
        'individu': 1,
        'manajemen': 1,
        'tahu': 1,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1
    },
    'doc1': {
        'manajemen': 1,
        'transfer': 1,
        'individu':1,
        'tahu':1,
        'transaksi': 1,
        'logistik': 1
    },
    'doc2': {
        'manajemen': 1,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1
    }
}
```

I want use Python to transform it to the following in a new dictionary:

```
{
    'doc0': {
        'individu': 1,
        'manajemen': 1,
        'tahu': 1,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1,
        'transfer':0
    },
    'doc1': {
        'individu': 1,
        'manajemen': 1,
        'tahu': 1,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1
    },
    'doc2': {
        'individu': 0,
        'manajemen': 1,
        'tahu': 0,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1,
        'transfer':0
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate your question a little bit?

Comment: Unless you can describe what rules you want to use to perform the data transformation no-one will be able to help you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will face the problem with the key ordering in a dictionary. The keys (or the key-value pairs) in the dictionary are sorted arbitrarily. The order is not fixed and can change in different steps.

To mitigate this problem you can use the `OrderedDict` from the module `collections`.

If I understand your problem, you want to bring in line your dictionaries and make them have the same keys. If there is a key in `doc1`, but `doc2` is missing it, so `doc2` should be updated with this key and the value 0. If that's right, then you rather want to duplicate the keys, not the values.

This is my try:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# your initial data
my_dict = {
    'doc0': {
        'individu': 1,
        'manajemen': 1,
        'tahu': 1,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1
    },
    'doc1': {
        'manajemen': 1,
        'transfer': 1,
        'individu':1,
        'tahu':1,
        'transaksi': 1,
        'logistik': 1
    },
    'doc2': {
        'manajemen': 1,
        'logistik': 1,
        'transaksi': 1
    }
}

# get all keys in a help list
list_of_keys = []
for key in my_dict:
    for dockey in my_dict[key]:
        if dockey not in list_of_keys:
            list_of_keys.append(dockey)
# sort the list
list_of_keys.sort()
# the list looks like this
# ['individu', 'logistik', 'manajemen', 'tahu', 'transaksi', 'transfer']

# now we can iterate through our data
# and align the keys and values in an OrderedDict

my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
# get the doc keys and update the ordered dictionary
for key in my_dict:
    my_ordered_dict.update([(key, OrderedDict())])

for i in list_of_keys:
    for key in my_dict:
        if i in my_dict[key].iterkeys():
            my_ordered_dict[key].update([(i, 1)])
        else:
            my_ordered_dict[key].update([(i, 0)])
```

Now you have all keys in every dictionary, they are sorted and the order is preserved. The initial data stays unchanged.

I didn't use any advanced features like list comprehensions, ternary operators or similar. The approach is a little bit naive and simple because you are a beginner, and I think it would be easier for you to understand every step.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: thank you so much :) yeah you're right this is what I mean. Thanks for your help :) it works for me

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please look also at the other answers, especially  `set`. It can help you to enhance the solution. You can mark the question as answered by selecting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following code :

```
>>> all = list(set([j for i in list(d.keys()) for j in list(d[i].keys())]))

>>> all
['transfer', 'tahu', 'transaksi', 'individu', 'manajemen', 'logistik']

>>> for k in all:
     for j in list(d.keys()):
         if not k in d[j].keys():
             d[j][k]=0

>>> d
{'doc0': {'individu': 1,
  'logistik': 1,
  'manajemen': 1,
  'tahu': 1,
  'transaksi': 1,
  'transfer': 0},
 'doc1': {'individu': 1,
  'logistik': 1,
  'manajemen': 1,
  'tahu': 1,
  'transaksi': 1,
  'transfer': 1},
 'doc2': {'individu': 0,
  'logistik': 1,
  'manajemen': 1,
  'tahu': 0,
  'transaksi': 1,
  'transfer': 0}}
```

I take all keys in the nested dictionary, and then create the values that don't exist (hence the zeroes in the last output).

Comment: thank you so much, your answer also works for me, it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, but to cause all the key/value pairs in dict2 to be added to dict1 or updated in dict1, you do `dict1.update(dict2)`. Example:

```
>>> dict1={"apples":14, "bananas":22}
>>> dict2={"apples":4, "pears":7}
>>> dict1.update(dict2)
>>> dict1
{'apples': 4, 'bananas': 22, 'pears': 7}
```

Alternatively if you want to copy keys and values from dict2 only if the key is not already in dict1, then

```
>>> dict1={"apples":14, "bananas":22}
>>> dict2={"apples":4, "pears":7}
>>> for k in set(dict2.keys()) - set(dict1.keys()): 
>>>     dict1[k]=dict2[k]
... 
>>> dict1
{'apples': 14, 'bananas': 22, 'pears': 7}
```